# Search a text in a column

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have an ASP.NET page and have a table looks like

```
Create table Test(id int, Users Varchar(MAX));
Insert into Test select 1, 'admin;operator;user1';
Insert into Test select 2, 'superadmin';
Insert into Test select 3, 'superadmin;admin';
```

Any of Test row can include more than one user, so I am dividing them by semicolon. I want to return the value when the client search in textbox, they will insert only: **admin**  I want to return only the rows which includes **admin**.

I can not use

```
select id,Users where Users like '%admin%'
```

Because in this case the query will return 2nd and 3rd columns which includes superadmin.

How can I get true result?

Comment: The problem is you're storing delimited data. Fix your design and you don't have this problem.

Comment: delimited `;` required in your operation?

Comment: As @Larnu mentioned, if possible change the design else the only option i see isto either create a function or stored procedure which takes the search string as input, first splits the results and store it in a temp table (Table variable) and filer out and return the results from there

Comment: Fix your schema. There are no second and third columsn there, it's just one column. You can't easily query text stored like that, even if you split the values. You can't accelerate such queries either because you can't index the individual values

Comment: Thank you for kind advice. But right now, i can not change the design of table. Because this is a token table and has more columns. One token may assign multiple users so in this case i will have to create same token for each users separately.

Comment: @Maestro00 you can't *not* change that schema. What you describe is a simple many-to-many table. It's trivial to create one *and* querying is fast if you index both ID columns. Finding matches is a cheap index seek. There's no way to index this `varchar(max)` column though, forcing a full table scan on each query, *and* an expensive substring search on top.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos and Larnu, Thanks for good explanation. Tbh i was thinking that using less rows is useful approach for me. But if i change the schema by good indexing as you mentioned, might be better approach for speed. Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be storing delimited data, if possible, normalize your database.
As this isn't always possible, you can get what you want with:

```
where CONCAT(';', Users, ';') like '%;admin;%'
```

Comment: This still requires a full table scan to find matches.

Comment: This returns exactly what i required. Thank you HoneyBadger.

Comment: Seems the OP thinks that delimited data speeds their database up, @PanagiotisKanavos (see their comment under my answer).

Comment: @Maestro00 it's not. This is the workaround until you fix the schema.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comment, you need to fix your design; what you're doing right now is breaking one of the fundamental Normal Form rules. That means, instead, have one row per user:

```
CREATE TABLE Test (uid int IDENTITY,
                   id int,
                   Username nvarchar(128));
INSERT INTO Test (id,
                  Username)
VALUES (1, N'admin'),
       (1, N'operator'),
       (1, N'user1'),
       (2, N'supermadmin'),
       (3, N'superadmin'),
       (3, N'admin');
```

Then you can simply use a `=` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM Test
WHERE Username = N'admin';
```

Comment: Thank you Larnu. I will consider your advice. But some of my columns include very long encrypted data, if i create several rows for only one item, that will make my database slower.

Comment: Searching for users using a `LIKE` like that is going to make it slower, @Maestro00 . Storing well formatted, non-delimited data will make it faster, not slower, as you're be able to properly index it. You are misinformed if you think delimited data speeds things up.

Comment: @Maestro00 no it won't. What you did already made your database orders of magnitude slower. Instead of using indexes to find matches, you now have to scan the entire table and search inside the values. For 10K rows, that's *at least* 10K times slower than using indexes - text searching in SQL is *slow*, definitely slower than equalitiy comparisons

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can try below query

```
SELECT * FROM #tmpTest where users like '%Admin%' AND Users not like 'superAdmin'
```

Comment: What about rows where `'superadmin'` and `'User1'` are a member?

Comment: You are right my bad I didn't realize that scenario Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But the case is not only about admin. There might be another usernames like admin1;meadmin